# How to resume the activity where you left off?

Tags: java, android

This is all the codes i have guys. I am pretty new in Android . I just want to resume my activity where i left off previously. As you see, my app is a simple counter where when you click the button, textview shows the number increasing.I wish to for example count up to 10 then exit from the app and then when i launch the activity again , wish to continue where i left off which is 10 in this case.Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int counter=0;
    TextView tv1;
    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                tv1.setText("" + counter);
            }
        });
```

Comment: override onPause() of the activity and save the current time count in the shared preferences. then next time you visit the app just check whether there is any value in the shared preferences. If present display the saved value else start the timer again

Comment: You need to store the count some where before your activity finishes and restore when its created. Use SharedPreferences

Comment: I have edited my answer, try `getSharedPreferences` instead of `activity.getSharedPreferences` before as my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look for tutorials about `SharedPreferences`.

You'll need to put the data in your overriden `onPause()` and read it in `onResume()`. If you're not familier with those, read about activity life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code will help you..

```
SharedPreferences myCount=null;   

@Override
    protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause()

     myCount=getSharedPreferences("countStore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myCount.edit();
    String cText=tv1.getText().toString();
    editor.putStringSet("count",cText);
     editor.commit();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
    myCount=getSharedPreferences("countStore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      if(myCount != null){
        String text = myCount.getString("count", null);

         if(text !=null){
         tv1.setText(text);
         }
       }

    }
```

Comment: having problem on context ....context.getSharedPreferences this is where i got problem..Do you have any idea what should i do ?

Comment: use this.getSharedPreferences().... or just getSharedPreferences()..check edited ans pls

Comment: Sorry for bothering you...I did changes but still having error on tv1.getText());...Pls help.

Comment: oky ... no problem... use tv1.getText().toString(); ..dont feel shy to  let me know for any problem

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("mySettings", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("myCounter", counter);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("mySettings", 0);
    counter = settings.getInt("myCounter", 0);
    tv1.setText(counter+"");
}
```

Comment: It did not work for me..when i exit the app and launch it again it refresh the activity.Cant continue where i left off...Thank you very much anyway

Comment: I'm sorry I missed a `commit();` after `editor.putInt(....)`. I re-edited the answer!

Comment: It worked perfectly.Thank you so much...As a last thing, pls also let me know what should i do if i have multiple variables apart from counter.For example , counter, counter_left, name_of_counter  ect...

Comment: Well if you need just a few variables to store offline while your app is not being used, then use sharedpreferences as before, just add more like `editor.putInt("myCounter", counter); editor.putInt("myCounterLeft", counterLeft); editor.putString("nameOfCounter", "Car counter");
    editor.commit();` but if variables to store become more, then I suggest you to take a look at local databases. Please, if my answer helped you, mark it as correct answer :D

Comment: it helped alot...I will.Thanks